# __autoload not respected when testing with PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, autoload

How can I make PHPUnit respect __autoload functions?

For example, I have these three files:

loader.php

```
function __autoload($name)
{
    echo "foo\n";
    require_once("$name.php");
}
```

test.php

```
require_once("loader.php");

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    function testFoo()
    {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

foo.php

```
require_once("loader.php");
new Foo();
```

As expected `php foo.php` errors out, saying that file "Foo.php" doesn't
exist. The `testFoo()` function however errors out by saying that there is
no such class as `Foo`, and never echos the "foo\n" line.

Comment: `__autoload` should work as long as you have php5... what version of php are you running?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

See this PHPUnit bugtracker entry: [`Upgrading to 3.5.10 has broken function of "autoload"`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/129)

**As of PHPUnit 3.5:**

> PHPUnit now uses an autoloader to load its classes. If the tested code requires an autoloader, use spl_autoload_register() to register it.

### Quick fix:

The only change required is to add `spl_autoload_register('__autoload')` in your bootstrap script.

### Longer fix:

If you can I'd suggest you just get rid of `__autoload` all together and use [`spl_autoload_register`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) in your application as it is the way to go with PHP 5 code. (If you only have one autoloader you can't use the autoloader of your framework and so on)

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`spl_autoload_register`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead of `__autoload`. `spl_autoload_register` allows for multipe autoloaders to work together without clobbering each other.

Answer (score 2):

PHPUnit uses spl_autoload_register which turns off __autoload.